# Able to update UI form Thread. Why?

Tags: android, multithreading, threadpool

As per the Docs we can't update the UI from background thread. But in my case I am able to update the UI without any issue. Check thread3. I also printed the thread name and which turn outs to be Thread-4.

Why is it not throwing exception for accessing main thread from background thread?

```
fun threadsWithThreadPoolExecutor(v: View) {
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    var endTime: Long = startTime
    val threadPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3)
    val thread1 = Thread(Runnable {
        Thread.sleep(7000)
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    })
    val thread2 = Thread(Runnable {
        Thread.sleep(10000)
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    })
    val thread3 = Thread(Runnable {
        Thread.sleep(3000)
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        tv_result.text = "This is from thread"
    })

    showProcessRunning()
    threadPoolExecutor.submit(thread1)
    threadPoolExecutor.submit(thread2)
    threadPoolExecutor.submit(thread3)

    Log.d("MyLog", thread3.name)

    Handler().postDelayed(Runnable {
        showTotalTime(startTime, endTime)
    }, 20000)
}
```

**UPDATE**
As someone mentioned in a comment why am I passing the thread in ThreadPoolExecutor#submit(), because it implements Runnable. Also, event if I don't use ThreadPool then also the issue is still there.

```
fun threadsWithoutExecutor(v: View) {
    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    var endTime: Long = startTime
    val thread1 = Thread(Runnable {
        Thread.sleep(7000)
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    })
    val thread2 = Thread(Runnable {
        Thread.sleep(10000)
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    })
    val thread3 = Thread(Runnable {
        tv_result.text = "sdadadasda"
        Thread.sleep(3000)
        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    })

    thread3.priority = Thread.MIN_PRIORITY
    showProcessRunning()
    thread1.start()
    thread2.start()
    thread3.start()

    Thread(Runnable {
        thread1.join()
        thread2.join()
        thread3.join()
        showTotalTime(startTime, endTime)
    }).start()
}
```

Comment: Are you using Android Kotlin Extensions?

Comment: Can you share the full code? Did you wait for 20 seconds?  It must crash when you reach `tv_result.text`

Comment: Which device and OS were you running on, because when I try above code, the app crashes right after 3 seconds.

Comment: I am not using any kotlin extensions

Comment: Yes I waited for 1 minute nothing unusual happens

Comment: @MikeM. Sorry for the trouble. I have updated the question.

Comment: I am using emulator running on Android O